# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id. Inserting Account as Customer Community User in Test

Tags: apex, unit-test, permissions, customer-community, lightning-community

I have a simple Apex controller method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean addAccount(String companyName) {

    try {

        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = companyName;
        acc.OwnerId = CommunityUtil.getCurrentUserContactOwnerId();

        insert acc;

        return true;

    } catch (Exception cause) {
        throw AuraHandledException(cause.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It works when I manually test, but my test fails with this error:

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

My Apex Test:

```
@isTest
public static void addAccount() {

    // arrange
    Id accountId = TestDataFactory.createAccount();
    Id contactId = TestDataFactory.getContactId(accountId);
    User u = TestDataFactory.createCustomerUser(contactId);
    Boolean response;

    // act
    System.runAs(u) {
        response = MyController.addAccount('Acme Inc');
    }

    // assert
    System.assertNotEquals(null, response);
    System.assertEquals(true, response);
}
```

I create the customer user like this:

```
public static User createCustomerUser(Id contactId) {

    User u = new user();

    u.FirstName = 'FirstName';
    u.LastName = 'LastName';
    u.Email = 'firstname.lastname@example.com';
    u.Alias = 'nickname';
    u.Username = 'firstname.lastname@example.com';
    u.CommunityNickname = 'nickname';
    u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_GB';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/London';
    u.profileId = getCommunityLoginProfile();
    u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.ContactId = contactId;
    u.IsActive = true;

    insert u;

    return u;
}
```

Prior to getting the `INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY` error, I wasn't setting the `OwnerId` on the `Account` record and I was getting error:

> OP_WITH_INVALID_USER_TYPE_EXCEPTION, Operation not valid for this user type: []

I think this issue was caused by my Customer Community `User` not having a `Role`, so I decided to set `Account.OwnerId` to the current users contact record `OwnerId`. But I am not sure that was right...

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Community user don't have permission "Create Account'

Comment: @BanshiLalDangi why does it work when I test it manually?

Comment: When you run manually it runs in System mode.

Comment: @BanshiLalDangi when I open the community in incognito mode and login, I can add Accounts...

Comment: Could you add some asserts and verify if the records are inserted in database, sometimes they fails silently in test classes; which breaks any logic afterwards.

Comment: @Raul i know the 3 setup lines work, because I am using them in 100 other tests. And there is no other logic afterwards...

Comment: There is no harm in trying, sometimes things go wrong unexpectedly.